# How to deploy docker images from the Docker on MacOs to the Docker machine in the VirtualBox on Windows

Tags: docker, virtual-machine, virtualbox, docker-machine

I have 2 machines : 
1) MacOs laptop 
2) Windows 7 pc.

Mac is too slow for deploying the whole application. So, i've created the docker machine on windows.

```
docker-machine create -d virtualbox my-app
docker-machine env my-app > connect.bat
```

I have the docker machine, that is accessible from the Windows by the tcp://192.168.99.100:2376.
Then I am able to build and run my docker images in that machine by

```
docker-compose build <image>
docker-compose up <image>
```

The issue is, that I need to have the application sources on this machine to be able to build containers from it, and as a result I need to code on this machine as well and connect to it through remote desktop that is very unconvinient.

The desired configuration is next: develop on Mac, then compile sources on it, build docker images and deploy to the docker machine that is running on Windows inside VirtualBox.

I've started trying to connect to this docker machine from Mac, copied the certificate files and try to connect

```
docker --tlsverify --tlscacert=ca.pem --tlscert=cert.pem --tlskey=key.pem -H=<WINDOWS_MACHINE_HOST>:2376 version
```

and get `error during connect: Get https://<WINDOWS_MACHINE_HOST>:2376/v1.32/version: x509: certificate is valid for 192.168.99.100, not <WINDOWS_MACHINE_HOST>`.

Attempts to regenerate the certificates by the instruction (https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/https/#secure-by-default) didn't help. I still got the same error.
The question is such case ever possible? If yes, the question is how? Would appreciate for any help